# What was Poland's involvement in the Vietnam War?

Tags: 20th-century, cold-war, poland, vietnam-war, reference

So far I've found a few stories about Poland's involvement in the Vietnam War:

- [historycy.org](http://www.historycy.org/index.php?showtopic=36539&st=15) (*in Polish*)
- [Operation Marigold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Marigold)
- [Multinational UN peacekeeping force](http://militaryhistorynow.com/2013/10/02/the-international-vietnam-war-the-other-world-powers-that-fought-in-south-east-asia/)
- [International Commission of Control and Supervision](http://thevietnamwar.info/what-countries-involved-in-the-vietnam-war-part-2/)
- ["The Yankee Air Polack" Donald Kutyna](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=462502153920757&id=266903283480646&substory_index=0)
- [Stefan Kubiak - Ho Chi Toan](http://historia.wp.pl/title,Ho-Chi-Toan-Polak-w-mundurze-wietnamskiej-armii,wid,17269505,wiadomosc.html?ticaid=1150e3)

Maybe you know any others?

Comment: H:SE discourages requests for references (unless they are canonical references as described in meta).  We also discourage open ended requests, since every answer is equal to every other, and they risk digressing into discussion or even political speech.  The question in the title is probably good; the question in the body is suspect, and may get closed.  OP may wish to revise the question to align the title with the body and get the desired answers.This particular question may be worth discussing in meta since it seems different from many of the other requests for reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mostly to supervise the enforcement of ceasefire and peace terms.

Polish involvement began in 1954 as a member of the [**International Commission of Control**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Control_Commission), together with Canada and India. That entity was setup at the [conclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Agreements) of the [First Indochina War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Indochina_War) to monitor the peace agreement. It was a general failure all around, resulting in the [Second Indochina War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indochina_Wars#Second_Indochina_War) when the United States eventually intervened in force.

The United Sates in turn began to [disengage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Peace_Accords) from Vietnam after 1973. The agreement dissolved the ICC and replaced it with the [**International Commission of Control and Supervision**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Commission_of_Control_and_Supervision), of which Poland was once again a member. As before, the commission was tasked with monitoring the implementation of the peace agreement, which similarly failed.

Comment: Why "mostly"? I suppose also that any intelligence activity is secret there?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch They also made some abortive attempts to broker peace. But the major notable activities were supervising the ceasefire, as described above.

Comment: I made some edits if you're interested.